# How to add an element to XML with Nokogiri and XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
  <!--
       The .NET 2.0 build of the console runner only 
    runs under .NET 2.0 or higher. The setting
    useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy only applies 
    under .NET 4.0 and permits use of mixed mode 
    assemblies, which would otherwise not load 
    correctly.
    -->
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <!-- Comment out the next line to force use of .NET 4.0 -->
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <!-- Ensure that test exceptions don't crash NUnit -->
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
    <!-- Run partial trust V2 assemblies in full trust under .NET 4.0 -->
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    <!-- Look for addins in the addins directory for now -->
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib;addins"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Using a Rakefile, I want to add an element in the `<startup>` section to say:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
```

to be:

```
<startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
```

Currently I have this:

```
task :update_test_runner_supported_runtime do
    test_runner_path   = 'Packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.4\tools\nunit-console-x86.exe.config'
    test_runner_config = Nokogiri::XML(open(functional_connection_path))
  functional_connection_config.xpath("//startup/")  #to find the start up element
  File.open(test_runner_path, 'w+') { |f| f.write(test_runner_config) } #to write the changes
end
```

What is the actual syntax to add this detail for the supported run time.

Comment: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Comment: hi @theTinMan, thanks for coming back with an answer. i haven't been working on this for a few days, I'll try out your suggestion and come back. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on.

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib;addins"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>

EOT

startup_node = doc.at('startup')
startup_node.delete('useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy')
startup_node.add_child('<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />')
```

[`at`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at-instance_method) in `doc.at('startup')` tells Nokogiri to find the first `<startup>` node. [`delete`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#remove_attribute-instance_method) is used to remove attributes of the node, and [`add_child`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#add_child-instance_method) adds a sub-node consisting of the string or another Node or NodeSet.

The `add_child` documentation says:

> Add `node_or_tags` as a child of this Node. `node_or_tags` can be a Nokogiri::XML::Node, a ::DocumentFragment, a ::NodeSet, or a string containing markup.

The code above results in:

```rb
doc.to_xml
# => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
#    "<configuration>\n" +
#    "  <startup>\n" +
#    "  <supportedRuntime version=\"v4.0\" sku=\".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2\"/></startup>\n" +
#    "  <runtime>\n" +
#    "    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled=\"1\"/>\n" +
#    "    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled=\"true\"/>\n" +
#    "    <assemblyBinding xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1\">\n" +
#    "      <probing privatePath=\"lib;addins\"/>\n" +
#    "    </assemblyBinding>\n" +
#    "  </runtime>\n" +
#    "</configuration>\n"
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation - i understand it better now :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can achieve this with a simple `sub!` call?

```rb
test_runner_config.sub!('<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">', '<startup>\n    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />')
File.open(test_runner_path, 'w+') { |f| f.write(test_runner_config) }
```

Comment: thanks for coming back - 
this results in an error : ```undefined method sub! for #<Nokogiri::XML::Document .....``` 
I get the same thing when I try ```sub``` and ```gsub```

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps gist will help. https://gist.github.com/bricker/3108044

Comment: The gist is interesting but it's the wrong way to change nodes or markup with Nokogiri when it makes it so easy to make the changes using its built-in methods.